# How can request the locks and deadlocks of a thread at runtime with C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, runtime, deadlock

In Java there are ThreadMXBean and ThreadInfo to requests information over the locks that a thread is holding at runtime.

Is this also possible with C#? If yes how can I do it?

Comment: Check out this tutorial on debugging deadlocks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2010/01/29/how-to-debug-deadlocks-using-windbg.aspx

Comment: That's a solid link on debugging deadlocks.

Comment: The problem is not a reproducible deadlock on the developer system. The target is logging on the customer system if some things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a runtime equivalent in C#.
If you need to track it you'll need to implement you're own wrapper around it.
Also consider using Monitor.TryEnter with a timeout if your application is sensitive to locking.

`lock (object)
    {
        // Synchronized code
    }`

Translates to,

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(object);
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(object);
}
```